# Fetch a random record with cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, random, fetch, cloudkit

Does anyone know a way to randomly grab one record out a Cloudkit database.
I can't seem to find a way. I have been able to pick one record by limiting the results returned by CKOperation but it's not random... 
I also can't seem to find any answers on this problem in the documentation...

Thanks!

(I am writing in swift)

Comment: How is the id generated? (is it a random md5 hash, is it an incrementing number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the recordID is a random guid you could generate your own guid and query for the first record that is greater than that.

When you don't create a recordID yourself, then it will be a random guid assigned by CloudKit.

This would not be a pure random selection. If 2 records are created with almost similar guids, then the greatest of these would have a smaller chance to be selected. The initial creation of the guids influence the chance a record is selected.

when doing the selection use a CKOperation, create a predicate where the recordID > a newly created guid, set the order to the recordID and select only 1 record. When the selection does not return a record, reverse the sort order and perform the same query.

a better solution to the random guid selection would be if you could number all records sequentially, fetch the largest number and just create a random number between 1 and that largest number.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I don't really understand, I am a bit new to this... So the approach would be to generate a random id (I presume the records already present would also have an id created in the same way) and then fetch CloudKit for an id greater than the generated one? But how would  this be random and work I don't really understand perfectly  (It wouldn't be a huge problem if I can't implement it since I also have another which doesn't require fetching for a random record, it would also be more lightweight but less flexible...)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I now understand 